# How to get last item for specific category in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, row, fetch

I have a table as below . i want to fetch  last item for category 320 .

```
id   |  category   |  city   |
 1   |  320        |  paris  |
 2   |  320        |  london |
 3   |  330        |  stock. |
 4   |  320        |  brussel|
 5   |  340        |  fifu   |
```

I want to get last item of category 320 which is

```
 id  |   category  |  city    |
  4  |      320    |  brussel |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
select t.*
from t
where category = 320
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Comment: @nohan . . . This would be about the most efficient way you can do this operation.  It will run faster with a composite index on `t(category, id)`.